# fiddler proxy ip doesn't work but localhost worked

Tags: fiddler

After setup my fiddler proxy,
I went to localhost:8888 and it was working fine, and it is shows

```
Fiddler Echo Service
```

But when I use IP 127.0.0.1:8888 or 127.0.0.2:8888, it doesn't work.

Comment: What *specifically* happens? Which browser? Do you have any third-party networking (e.g. VPN) or security (AV/anti-malware/etc) software installed? Which operating system do you have installed? If you have Win8+ and are using Immersive IE, you need to push the `WinConfig` button in Fiddler's toolbar to add an app-container exemption.

Answer (score 0):

Use `netstat -ab`, find `8888` in netstat report.

May be you use ipv6 (`[::1]:8888`). And `[::1]:8888` == `localhost:8888`.

What is `Fiddler Echo Service`?

Comment: Fiddler's "Echo Service" is the page shown when you navigate directly to the Fiddler proxy endpoint in a browser window.